# How does Pythons logging format string work?

Tags: python, logging

I have seen [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects) but I don't get it.

When I have a log formatting string like

```
'%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)-15s %(message)s'
```

what does the `s` after the parentheses mean? What effect has `-8s`?

From looking at the output, I think it is the minimum length of the string. But why is not the usual formatting syntax

```
'{asctime} {levelname:<8} {name:<15} {message}'
```

used?

Is it possible to have custom values in there (e.g. an ID which identifies what type of element was currently handled), or does this have to be in the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why is not the usual formatting syntax used?

You can use it.  Just specify the keyword argument `style='{'` when you configure logging.  They did not change it to the default, in order to keep backwards compat (the logging module predates `str.format` style formatting)

> what does the s after the parentheses mean?

"s" means use plain **s**tring representation.  Compare "d" for **d**igits.  This is printf style syntax.

> What effect has -8s?

Align left, pad to 8 width

```
>>> '%(foo)-8s' % {'foo': 'hello'}
'hello   '
```

> Is it possible to have custom values in there (e.g. an ID which identifies what type of element was currently handled), or does this have to be in the message?

Yes, but don't bother trying to get stdlib logging to do this stuff.  Go directly to [structlog](https://structlog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).